# Saving to database issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, crud

I am building a database and I am getting an issue with my create action.  My code for the create action is:

```
 def create
        @skills = Skill.new(params[:skill])
      if @skills.save
            redirect_to :action => 'index'
      else
            @skills = Skill.find(:all)
            render :action => 'new'
      end
   end
```

and my error message is this:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in SkillsController#create
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

I assume there is a problem and I am not saving all the needed params but I am not sure.  Thanks anyone who knows what might be going wrong and I will keep messing around with it myself.  Thanks again.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Strong Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). You may want to take a look through the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller add something like this:

```
private

  def skill_params
    params.require(:skill).permit(:attribute_1, :attribute_2, :attribute_3)
  end
```

then change create to:

```
def create
  @skills = Skill.new(skill_params)
  if @skills.save
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  else
    @skills = Skill.find(:all)
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

This is specific to Rails 4: this version of ruby on rails fordids direct usage of the params to instanciate a new Model object.

It makes your application more safe by protecting it against some vulnerabilities: for example, imagine if someone requests your application to create a new user and passes `admin: true` as parameter. The old way may create an admin user. On the contrary, the Rails 4 way force you to filter the parameters.

Comment: doing that gave me an odd error of::::::::Unknown action
The action 'create' could not be found for SkillsController

Comment: @ZachyBear Make sure create is not under private. It must be above private and the definition of skill_params should be at the bottom of SkillsController

Comment: thank you it was at the top and is probably the issue!

Comment: That cleared one bug and gave another which is::::::::ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SkillsController#create
SQLite3::ConstraintException: skills.title may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "skills" ("created_at") VALUES (?)

Comment: @ZachyBear, it looks like title is required but not added in the form. Check that. Make sure its also permitted and the definitions of skill+params

Comment: I need to just get rid of that title param all together. I don't think a skill needs a title because it speaks for itself.  Thank you and I will attempt to cleanse my DB of the :title param.  More advice is always welcomed and thanks again for guiding me through my errors.